What is the meaning of "$m$" and "$2$" in "$m \angle GLI = 2 m \angle GLH$"?
So I have this math problem that has an answer that looks like this.
$$m∠GLI = 2m∠GLH$$
The $m$ means the angle is congruent or of having equal length or measure right?
I was confused, though, because I haven't learned this yet, but what does the $2$ in front of the $m$ mean? Or in a broader sense, what does the number represent?
Here is the included problem.


Absent context, we'd just be guessing.  If you want a guess, they are distinguishing between the angle as a geometric object and the measure of the angle, which is a number.  In whuich case the $2$ would just mean twice the number, as usual.  But it is just a guess.  If you can, include a link to the source of the problem or write out the entire problem here.

Since $\text m\angle ABC$ means the measure of angle $ABC$, $2 \text m\angle ABC$ may mean twice its measure.


The m means the angle is congruent or of having equal length or measure right?

Generally, it does: $m \angle A$ typically means "the measure of angle $A$", and $m \angle ABC$ would mean "the measure of the angle formed by going from the vertices $A$ to $B$ to $C$, with $B$ as the corner of the angle."

I was confused, though, because I haven't learned this yet, but what does the 2 in front of the m, mean?

It just means "times two." That is, "$m \angle A = 2 m \angle B$" would mean "$m\angle A$ is twice as large as $m\angle B$."
Perhaps it might be more clearly written as
$$
m \angle A = 2 \cdot m \angle B
$$

Thank you so much for this answer!! I was stuck on this and turns out it is a lot simpler than I thought.
